# Data storage format for unstructured data rows on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, serialization, hdfs, apache-flink, sequencefile

We are consuming very large data that needs to be written as fast as we receive and we are using HDFS, so we prefer using it. The data is almost unstructured, and we will be doing basic queries on them rarely. The data is flat with some fields, each row representing another data.

```
key1=str key2=30.3 key3=longtexthere
```

Another data row:

```
key1=3 key5=abc
```

SequenceFile seemed the most natural one but I could not find how to store multiple rows in a single SequenceFile.

Currently, in our temporary solution, we have multiple writers that writes to multiple text files. So when querying is needed, we read them in parallel. However, current text files contains 1000s of rows and I don't think creating a single SequenceFile for each row would be feasiable, it would incur much overhead for storing metadata and reading many too many files at once when querying.

I think the problem can be solved by using HBase or Cassandra, a columunar database but we are almost required to use HDFS. Am I missing something with SequenceFiles or we should really use a columunar database?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of keys/columns ?

Comment: @oae No, while they are not fixed, they are rarely extended, meaning sometimes we add new columns but the old data does not have them.

Answer (score 1):

So sequence file format is like this:

`<key, value>
<key, value>
<key, value>
...`

where the key is a WritableComparable and the value is a Writable.
Now what a lot of people are doing - and you could do the same - is:

- Only use the key OR the value 'column'
- Implement a custom Writable which wraps a set of other Writables (call it record, row, ...)

That way you can model everything you want. That record writable could have a fixed schema, like it contains 'IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable' (depending on you fields). Or in case you don't wanna support different types, you could use the existing ArrayWritable as your 'record'.
Knowing the schema of each file (e.g. put it into the metadata of the sequence file, will allow you to do reads on files with different/evolved schema's.

So its a lot of handcrafting, but build can very efficient and flexible structure. Never used it, but take a look at http://pangool.net/userguide/schemas.html, think they already modeled suche a flexible record/tuple schema on top of sequence files.

Bottom line, i think you can achieve what you want with sequence files.
However i would recommend to also have a look at columnar file formats like [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) or [ORC files](https://orc.apache.org/). Those come with their own tradeoffs, but you will have a higher compression rate and selective reads (column projection, filter pushdown). Also you don't have to invent the schema/tuple structure.